Show some labels in WooCommerce admin Order customer formatted address
How to show labels for WooCommerce default fields in admin Order Detail Page.


Anyone, please let me know How to show labels for WooCommerce default fields in admin Order Detail Page.

To make changes to the formatted billing address in admin order edit pages try the following (Note that you may need to make some adjustments, to get the desired display):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 'filter_admin_order_formatted_billing_address', 10, 3 );
function filter_admin_order_formatted_billing_address( $address, $raw_address, $order ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow; 

    $address .= '<br>' . $pagenow . '<br>' . $typenow;

    if ( ( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) 
    || ( $pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page'])  && isset($_GET['action']) 
    && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-orders' && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' ) ) :

    $address = $raw_address['first_name'] . ' ' . $raw_address['last_name'] . '<br>';

    if ( isset($raw_address['company']) && $raw_address['company'] ) {
        $address .= $raw_address['company'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['address_1']) && $raw_address['address_1'] ) {
        $address .= __('Address') . ': '. $raw_address['address_1'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['address_2']) && $raw_address['address_2'] ) {
        $address .= __('Villa/Bldg/Number') . ': '. $raw_address['address_2'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['postcode']) && $raw_address['postcode'] ) {
        $address .= __('Zone Number') . ': '. $raw_address['postcode'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['city']) && $raw_address['city'] ) {
        $address .= $raw_address['city'] . '<br>';
    }

    $states = WC()->countries->get_states( esc_attr($raw_address['country']) );

    if ( isset($raw_address['state']) && isset($states[$raw_address['state']]) ) {
        $address .= $states[$raw_address['state']] . '<br>';
    }

    $countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

    if ( isset($raw_address['country']) && isset($countries[$raw_address['country']]) ) {
        $address .= $countries[$raw_address['country']] . '<br>';
    }

    endif;

    return $address;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

For Shipping formatted address (if needed), use:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_shipping_address', 'filter_admin_order_formatted_shipping_address', 10, 3 );
function filter_admin_order_formatted_shipping_address( $address, $raw_address, $order ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow; 

    $address .= '<br>' . $pagenow . '<br>' . $typenow;

    if ( ( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) 
    || ( $pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page'])  && isset($_GET['action']) 
    && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-orders' && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' ) ) :

    $address = $raw_address['first_name'] . ' ' . $raw_address['last_name'] . '<br>';

    if ( isset($raw_address['address_1']) && $raw_address['address_1'] ) {
        $address .= __('Address') . ': '. $raw_address['address_1'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['address_2']) && $raw_address['address_2'] ) {
        $address .= __('Villa/Bldg/Number') . ': '. $raw_address['address_2'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['postcode']) && $raw_address['postcode'] ) {
        $address .= __('Zone Number') . ': '. $raw_address['postcode'] . '<br>';
    }

    if ( isset($raw_address['city']) && $raw_address['city'] ) {
        $address .= $raw_address['city'] . '<br>';
    }

    $states = WC()->countries->get_states( esc_attr($raw_address['country']) );

    if ( isset($raw_address['state']) && isset($states[$raw_address['state']]) ) {
        $address .= $states[$raw_address['state']] . '<br>';
    }

    $countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

    if ( isset($raw_address['country']) && isset($countries[$raw_address['country']]) ) {
        $address .= $countries[$raw_address['country']] . '<br>';
    }

    endif;

    return $address;
}


I am trying to make bold of those label text but I am getting error.
Could you please assist me to make bold of the label.
